# How to configure a connection to the multiple RabbitMQ nodes?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-integration-amqp

I can configure the RabbitMQ client connection in two ways:

1. comma-separated list of IP addresses
2. host name that is DNS A record with multiple IP addresses

Will RabbitMQ Client connect to another node when the one with which is connected will fail?

Will do it in both cases?

Comment: Please, ask such a question on RabbitMQ user group https://groups.google.com/forum/?#!forum/rabbitmq-users. They don't monitor SO.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work as described. Give it a try yourself! I suggest using [`toxiproxy`](https://github.com/Shopify/toxiproxy) to interrupt a connection and force a reconnect to another node.